# PHP GD Image creation by passing multidimensional array urlencode urldecode

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, gd, urlencode

I am trying to generating a graph by using php GD. I am passing data from html to controller graph function. The whole thing works on my localhost, but on my live server the graph image is not creating. I am using PHP 5.5 on my local ubuntu 14.04 machine... The live server is using Php 5.4 on debian wheezy... I have checked in both machine GD library is installed..

After inspecting some I suspect I am doing something wrong when doing urlencode and urldecode or in my view when creating multidimensional array.

Here is my controller graph function:

```
public function graph1()
{
include('phpgraphlib.php');
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(600,300);

$data1 = unserialize(urldecode(stripslashes($_GET['mydata1'])));

$line1 = array_column($data1, 'line1');
$line2 = array_column($data1, 'line2');


$graph->addData($line1,$line2);
$graph->setBars(false);
//$graph->setGrid(false);
$graph->setGridColor("238, 238, 238");
$graph->setLine(true);
$graph->setDataPoints(true);
$graph->setDataPointColor('160,160,160');
$graph->setDataValues(true);
$graph->setDataValueColor('0,0,0');
$graph->setGoalLine(.0025);
$graph->setGoalLineColor('red');
$graph->setLineColor("255, 167, 78", "67, 162, 255","blue");
//$graph->setLegend(true);
//$graph->setLegendTitle("Apples", "Pears");
$graph->createGraph();
}
```

Here is my view from where I am passing my data:

```
<?php

$data1 = array();

foreach ($line1 as $field => $label){
if (count($points) > 0 && isset($points[0]->$field)){
  $i = 0; 
  $total = count($points); 
  $total = $total > 30 ? 30 : $total;
  foreach ($points as $point){
    if ($i >= $total){
      break;
    }

    $data1 []['line1'] = $point -> $field; 
    $i++;
  }
  }
  }

foreach ($line2 as $field => $label){
 if (count($points) > 0 && isset($points[0]->$field)){
  $i = 0; 
  $total = count($points); 
  $total = $total > 30 ? 30 : $total;
  foreach ($points as $point){
    if ($i >= $total){
      break;
    }

    $data1 []['line2'] = $point -> $field; 
    $i++;
  }
}
}

<img src="<?php echo site_url('/g1/g2/graph1')."?mydata1=".urlencode(serialize($data1)); ?>" />
```

This code is not creating the image on live server.. Really great if anyone can suggest me what to do?

Here is the url value of imgsrc from my localhost:

```
http://localhost/site/index.php/g1/g2/graph1?mydata1=a%3A12%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2292%22%3B%7Di%3A1%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22144%22%3B%7Di%3A2%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22110%22%3B%7Di%3A3%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22100%22%3B%7Di%3A4%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22365%22%3B%7Di%3A5%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22185%22%3B%7Di%3A6%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22176%22%3B%7Di%3A7%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22234%22%3B%7Di%3A8%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22358%22%3B%7Di%3A9%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22201%22%3B%7Di%3A10%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22144%22%3B%7Di%3A11%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22112%22%3B%7D%7D
```

Here is the url value of img src from Live server:

```
https://mysite.com/index.php/g1/g2/graph1?mydata1=a%3A12%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2292%22%3B%7Di%3A1%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22144%22%3B%7Di%3A2%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22110%22%3B%7Di%3A3%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22100%22%3B%7Di%3A4%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22365%22%3B%7Di%3A5%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22185%22%3B%7Di%3A6%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22176%22%3B%7Di%3A7%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22234%22%3B%7Di%3A8%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22358%22%3B%7Di%3A9%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22201%22%3B%7Di%3A10%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22144%22%3B%7Di%3A11%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22112%22%3B%7D%7D
```

Also if I set pdf debug tru then this debug error shown in live server:

```
mPDF error: IMAGE Error (https://mysite.com/index.php/g1/g2/graph1?mydata1=a%3A12%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2292%22%3B%7Di%3A1%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22144%22%3B%7Di%3A2%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22110%22%3B%7Di%3A3%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22100%22%3B%7Di%3A4%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22365%22%3B%7Di%3A5%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22185%22%3B%7Di%3A6%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22176%22%3B%7Di%3A7%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22234%22%3B%7Di%3A8%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22358%22%3B%7Di%3A9%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22201%22%3B%7Di%3A10%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22144%22%3B%7Di%3A11%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22line1%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22112%22%3B%7D%7D): Could not find image file
```

Comment: When you load the HTML on your server and View Source, what value do get in the IMG tag SRC attribute?

Comment: I have edited the question and in there provide the attribute

Comment: What do you get if you load the mPDF error URL directly in your browser?

Comment: Blank page... at corner image icon ... when I pass static data from view like this: $ data=array ("max"-》"1",....) the live server can create the graph image.. but for dynamic data in 2d array it fails

Comment: So, to clarify, as you say, "dynamic data in 2d array" works on localhost, but not on the server.

Comment: Yes.. its fully working on localhost.. but not on live server.. nd the local pc has php 5.5 but server have 5.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68293/discussion-between-bloodyknuckles-and-oxvoxic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, PHP function `array_column` began it's life with PHP 5.5.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php 
(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)

So for 5.4 friendly code you can replace:

```
$line1 = array_column($data1, 'line1');
$line2 = array_column($data1, 'line2');
```

With:

```
$line1 = array();
$line2 = array();

foreach ( $data1 as $line_array ) {
    if ( isset($line_array['line1']) ) { $line1[] = $line_array['line1']; }
    if ( isset($line_array['line2']) ) { $line2[] = $line_array['line2']; }
}
```

Here's a demo you can punch in here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

```
<?php

$data1 = array(
      array('line1' => 165)
    , array('line1' => 180)
    , array('line1' => '')
    , array('line1' => 140)
    , array('line2' => '')
    , array('line2' => 50)
    , array('line2' => 68)
    , array('line2' => 80)
);

$line1 = array();
$line2 = array();

foreach ( $data1 as $line_array ) {
    if ( isset($line_array['line1']) ) { $line1[] = $line_array['line1']; }
    if ( isset($line_array['line2']) ) { $line2[] = $line_array['line2']; }
}

print_r($line1);
print_r($line2);

?>
```

`print_r` -ing $line1 and $line2 gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 165
    [1] => 180
    [2] => 
    [3] => 140
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 68
    [3] => 80
)
```